# Mule ESB WebsphereMQ connection with JMS connector works in Mule Design, but not standalone server

Tags: mule, ibm-mq

I am new to Mule and followed this [blog](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2011/03/webspheremq-integration-using-mule-esb-community-edition/) to create a "websphere-mq connector" through the jms connector. I am using the community edition.

In order to connect to the websphere mq server, I must run the application under a specific Windows username. Running the mule application in Mule Design under the specific username, I am able to connect and receive messages. However, I am unable to connect to the websphere mq server through the standalone application running on a windows server. I changed the user on the service that is running mule to the specific user but am unable to get authorization to the websphere mq server.

Any additional insight would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stand alone application runs the Tanuki Software wrapper as the user assigned to the environment variable %USERNAME% in windows. Even though I updated the user in the Mule service to run as the approved user, the wrapper will take the environment variable.

To solve the problem, I updated the wrapper.conf file to include the following:

```
set.USERNAME=<approvedUsername>
```

the environment variable %USERNAME% is now set to the approved username, in which mule will allow the JMS connector to the authenticate with the correct username.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest reviewing the ["Getting going without turning off security"](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/messaging/entry/getting_going_without_turning_off_mq_security?lang=en) article for an introduction to MQ security. This might help get the MQ system correctly configured.

Comment: I don't have control over the WebsphereMQ server. Essentially I am the client and trying to connect to the broker. I am able to connect to the broker through Anypoint Studio; however, when I deploy the mule app to the standalone client, I get the following exception: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2035' ('MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED'). Ultimately I'm curious to know how would I find out what user credentials is being passed to the MQ server? I have reached out to the broker to have them check the log, but was curious if I could check myself.

Comment: Do you know what the user/password supplied to the JMS CreationConnection API - understand that might not be obvious if in Mule. If there's not one specified there the userid will most probably be the user of the process/JVM that is running Mule.   

QM Logs are the most efficient way of working out the user that is come in.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it added some additional insight to the issue, which I was able to solve.